# new Date() TimeStamp differences between Front-/BackEnd

Tags: json, timestamp, frontend, backend

I'm sending a `json` body from frontend to my backend, but the timestamp between frontend and backend are different. I'm using `new Date().`

```
Output Frontend: Wed Oct 07 2020 10:12:55 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time). 

Output Backend: "timestamp":"2020-10-07T08:12:43.746Z"
```

I don't understand, why I get the timestamp wrong in my Backend. The Frontend is sending the correct time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just different time Formating; Your Backend says Year-Month-Day Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Milisecconds
Your Frontend says Dayname Month Day Year Hours+2:Minutes:Secconds

Answer (score 0):

If you try

- In backend `(new Date(2023,6,1)).getTime()`
- In frontend `(new Date(Date.UTC(2023,6,1))).getTime()` (or simply `Date.UTC(2023,6,1)`)
  =>You'll the same value 1688169600000

But if you `(new Date(2023,6,1)).getTime()` in frontend, you'll get `1688162400000` (2h earlier)

To conclude, backend uses UTC time system whereas fontend uses local time of your browser